# USB 3.0 SuperSpeed SATA bridge only detected as High-Speed device

Tags: usb, storage, sata

I have some USB/SATA bridge device (Scythe Kama Connect) that claims (on its colorful box) to support USB 3.0 SuperSpeed.

However, when I connect it to an AlderLake Linux system it's only detected as HyperSpeed device:

```
May 21 18:50:55 usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd              
May 21 18:50:55 usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2509, bcdDevice= 1.00                                                                                   
May 21 18:50:55 usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=11, SerialNumber=3      
May 21 18:50:55 usb 3-3: Product: Usb production                                        
May 21 18:50:55 usb 3-3: Manufacturer: JMicron                                          
May 21 18:50:55 usb 3-3: SerialNumber: 00A123456789                                     
May 21 18:50:55 usb-storage 3-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected                   
May 21 18:50:55 scsi host0: usb-storage 3-3:1.0                                         
May 21 18:50:56 scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Jmicron  Corp.  1234 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS  
May 21 18:50:56 sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0                            
May 21 18:50:56 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1465149168 512-byte logical blocks: (750 GB/699 GiB)  
May 21 18:50:56 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off                                  
May 21 18:50:56 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00                               
May 21 18:50:56 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found                            
May 21 18:50:56 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through                   
May 21 18:50:56 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk                                    
May 21 18:51:04 usb usb2-port2: attempt power cycle                                     
May 21 18:51:12 usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Thus, I'm only seeing IO throughput of 23 MiB/s or so when accessing a connected hard-disk.

FWIW, that system is on Fedora 37 (6.2.15-200.fc37.x86_64) and that device is directly connected to a laptop-chassis USB port.

Is there some trick how to convince/force Linux to detect this device as a SuperSpeed one?